# In my Cucumber framework, Why Examples is repeated as each step in Intelij IDE Console

Tags: automation, frameworks, cucumber, intellij-14, cucumber-junit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZ88T.jpg)

I want each steps of a scenario outline need to be shown in the console.The values I pass through examples can be shown inside the steps.

which is working for other feature files, only for this file it is not working

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.